# Using calipers in GenMatch to enourage more pairs

Tags: r, match, matching

So following the example from the Matching package and in particular the GenMatch example

[Link to package here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matching/Matching.pdf)

Following the example in `GenMatch`

library(Matching)

```
data(lalonde)
attach(lalonde)

X = cbind(age, educ, black, hisp, married, nodegr, u74, u75, re75, re74)

BalanceMat <- cbind(age, educ, black, hisp, married, nodegr, u74, u75, re75, re74,
                    I(re74*re75))

genout <- GenMatch(Tr=treat, X=X, BalanceMatrix=BalanceMat, estimand="ATE", M=1,
                   pop.size=16, max.generations=10, wait.generations=1)

genout$matches
genout$ecaliper

Y=re78/1000

mout <- Match(Y=Y, Tr=treat, X=X, Weight.matrix=genout)
summary(mout)
```

We see 185 treated observation are paired with 270 non-treatment observation.
Now we want to relax this to allow for more flexible pairing on the age criteria.

We can generate a table with the teatment cases and their age on the left and the control case and age on the right by:

```
pairs <- data.frame(mout$index.treated, lalonde$age[mout$index.treated], mout$index.control, lalonde$age[mout$index.control])
```

Now using the `caliper` function of the `Match()` we should be able to generate a more relaxed match.

We see that `sd(lalonde$age)` gives us a SD of 7 years for our table, so lets try and match for this limit. Would one simply

```
mout2 <- Match(Y=Y, Tr=treat, X=X, Weight.matrix=genout, caliper=c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
summary(mout2)
```

it appear not because less `Matched number of observations` have occured in `mout2` than `mout1`.

So where have I gone wrong?
The values of zero must be included in caliper or else an error is returned if they are blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first call to GenMatch did not impose *any* caliper. Your second call imposed a caliper so the number of matches will decrease. If you want to increase the number of matches in your first call, see the "M" option. You probably want something like 1-to-2 matching, etc.

Comment: So is this the correct way to 'relax' the weight value for the age variable??

genout <- GenMatch(Tr=treat, X=X, BalanceMatrix=BalanceMat, estimand="ATE", M=1,
                   pop.size=16, max.generations=10, wait.generations=1,
                   caliper=c(2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))